# How to get starting date in a Week based on week number using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I need help on getting the starting date of a week from a given week number in vb.net.

I have combobox binded with items 1-53 as week numbers. What I want to do is whenever I select a specific week number, it will return the first date of that selected week number.

For instance I have selected week Number 46, it must return November 11, 2013 as first date of week number 46.

I have tried the following codes and it returns only the first date of a week from a current week number.

```
DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Now, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday) + 1, Now)
```

Is there any possible way that can return my expected output?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Private Sub TestDateAdd()
    Dim weekStart As DateTime = GetWeekStartDate(46, 2013)
    Console.WriteLine(weekStart)
End Sub


Private Function GetWeekStartDate(weekNumber As Integer, year As Integer) As Date
    Dim startDate As New DateTime(year, 1, 1)
    Dim weekDate As DateTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, weekNumber - 1, startDate)
    Return DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (-weekDate.DayOfWeek) + 1, weekDate)
End Function
```

Disclaimer: I only really tested this with the one input, you probably want to make sure that it works as expected for different years, etc..

Comment: Thanks Sir! I got my expected output :-)

Comment: This does not work if the year-1 had 53 weeks. For instance, in 2020 the last day of the year is a Thursday, therefore the last week of the year is considered w53. The first day of 2021 w1 is 4/1/2021 and not 1/1/2021.

Comment: Affirm, this doesn't provide a correct result for 2021 (was working in 2020) for ISO week (first four days week).

Comment: Well, it worked for 7 years... good run I guess :-D. If any of you have a better solution, please do provide an answer here for future copy/paste coders ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Function FirstDateOfWeek(ByVal Year As Integer, ByVal Week As Integer, Optional FirstDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday) As Date
    Dim dt As Date = New Date(Year, 1, 1)
    If dt.DayOfWeek > 4 Then dt = dt.AddDays(7 - dt.DayOfWeek) Else dt = dt.AddDays(-dt.DayOfWeek)
    dt = dt.AddDays(FirstDayOfWeek)
    Return dt.AddDays(7 * (Week - 1))
End Function
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for your answer.

Comment: This is correct for "First Four Days Week", which should be used in most countries respecting international standards. ISO itself, however, allows some variants, AFAIK.